# What's the theoretical basis for existential types?

Tags: haskell, types, type-systems, existential-type, quantifiers

The [Haskell Wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types#Explaining_the_term_existential) does a good job of explaining how to use existential types, but I don't quite grok the theory behind them.

Consider this example of an existential type:

```
data S = forall a. Show a => S a      -- (1)
```

to define a type wrapper for things that we can convert to a `String`. The wiki mentions that what we *really* want to define is a type like

```
data S = S (exists a. Show a => a)    -- (2)
```

i.e. a true "existential" type - loosely I think of this as saying "the data constructor `S` takes any type for which a `Show` instance **exists** and wraps it". In fact, you could probably write a GADT as follows:

```
data S where                          -- (3)
    S :: Show a => a -> S
```

I haven't tried compiling that, but it seems as though it should work. To me, the GADT is obviously equivalent to the code (2) that we'd like to write.

However, it's completely not obvious to me why (1) is equivalent to (2). Why does moving the data constructor to the outside turn the `forall` into an `exists`?

The closest thing I can think of are [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws#Extensions) in logic, where interchanging the order of a negation and a quantifier turns existential quantifiers into universal quantifiers, and vice-versa:

```
¬(∀x. px) ⇔ ∃x. ¬(px)
```

but data constructors seem to be a totally different beast to the negation operator.

What is the theory that lies behind the ability to define existential types using `forall` instead of the non-existent `exists`?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

First of all, take a look at the "Curry Howard correspondence" which states that the types in a computer program correspond to formulas in intuitionistic logic.  Intuitionistic logic is just like the "regular" logic you learned in school but without the law of the excluded middle or double negation elimination:

- Not an axiom: P ⇔ ¬¬P (but P ⇒ ¬¬P is fine)
- Not an axiom: P ∨ ¬P

### Laws of logic

You are on the right track with DeMorgan's laws, but first we are going to use them to derive some new ones.  The relevant version of DeMorgan's laws are:

- ∀x. P(x)  =  ¬∃x. ¬P(x)
- ∃x. P(x)  =  ¬∀x. ¬P(x)

We can derive (∀x. P ⇒ Q(x))  =  P ⇒ (∀x. Q(x)):

1. (∀x. P ⇒ Q(x))
2. (∀x. ¬P ∨ Q(x))
3. ¬P ∨ (∀x. Q(x))
4. P ⇒ (∀x. Q(x))

And (∀x. Q(x) ⇒ P)  =  (∃x. Q(x)) ⇒ P (this one is used below):

1. (∀x. Q(x) ⇒ P)
2. (∀x. ¬Q(x) ∨ P)
3. (¬¬∀x. ¬Q(x)) ∨ P
4. (¬∃x. Q(x)) ∨ P
5. (∃x. Q(x)) ⇒ P

Note that these laws hold in intuitionistic logic as well.  The two laws we derived are cited in the paper below.

### Simple Types

The simplest types are easy to work with.  For example:

```
data T = Con Int | Nil
```

The constructors and accessors have the following type signatures:

```
Con :: Int -> T
Nil :: T

unCon :: T -> Int
unCon (Con x) = x
```

### Type Constructors

Now let's tackle type constructors.  Take the following data definition:

```
data T a = Con a | Nil
```

This creates two constructors,

```
Con :: a -> T a
Nil :: T a
```

Of course, in Haskell, type variables are implicitly universally quantified, so these are really:

```
Con :: ∀a. a -> T a
Nil :: ∀a. T a
```

And the accessor is similarly easy:

```
unCon :: ∀a. T a -> a
unCon (Con x) = x
```

### Quantified types

Let's add the existential quantifier, ∃, to our original type (the first one, without the type constructor).  Rather than introducing it in the type definition, which doesn't look like logic, introduce it in the constructor / accessor definitions, which do look like logic.  We'll fix the data definition later to match.

Instead of `Int`, we will now use `∃x. t`.  Here, `t` is some kind of type expression.

```
Con :: (∃x. t) -> T
unCon :: T -> (∃x. t)
```

Based on the rules of logic (the second rule above), we can rewrite the type of `Con` to:

```
Con :: ∀x. t -> T
```

When we moved the existential quantifier to the outside (prenex form), it turned into a universal quantifier.

So the following are theoretically equivalent:

```
data T = Con (exists x. t) | Nil
data T = forall x. Con t | Nil
```

Except there is no syntax for `exists` in Haskell.

In non-intuitionistic logic, it is permissible to derive the following from the type of `unCon`:

```
unCon :: ∃ T -> t -- invalid!
```

The reason this is invalid is because such a transformation is not permitted in intuitionistic logic.  So it is impossible to write the type for `unCon` without an `exists` keyword, and it is impossible to put the type signature in prenex form.  It's hard to make a type checker guaranteed to terminate in such conditions, which is why Haskell doesn't support arbitrary existential quantifiers.

### Sources

"First-class Polymorphism with Type Inference", Mark P. Jones, Proceedings of the 24th ACM SIGPLAN-SIGACT symposium on Principles of programming languages ([web](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/%7Empj/pubs/fcp.html))

Comment: You probably meant P ∨ ¬P (which is the law of excluded middle). P ∧ ¬P isn't axiom in any logic (it's quite easy to derive contracition using this).

Comment: Quite right, fixed.  It is superlatively easy to derive a contradiction from "P ∧ ¬P", since "P ∧ ¬P" is usually used as the definition of contradiction itself.

Comment: Cheers. And if I may, double negation elimination and excluded middle are equivalent, so axioms of classical logic mention only one of them. Strictly speaking, they are also equivalent to Peirce's Law, which has the nice propery of using only logical implication (the law is as follows: ((P ⇒ Q) ⇒ P) ⇒ P). Peirce's law has CH correspondence to `call/cc`.

Comment: @Vitus My mind is blown. But I have a question: `callCC` corresponds to Peirce's law, and Peirce's law is equivalent to the law of the excluded middle, but `callCC` is clearly a part of Haskell and Dietrich's post suggests that law of excluded middle is a part of non-intuitionistic logic, whereas Haskell is based on intuitionistic logic. How can these statements be reconciled?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: That's because Haskell's `callCC` type isn't `((a → b) → a) → a`, but rather `∀ r. ((a → (b → r) → r) → (a → r) → r) → (a → r) → r`. The trick is of course that continuations aren't primitive in Haskell and when you want to use them, you have to explicitly state that; they are implemented as `∀ r. (a → r) → r`. On the other hand in Scheme, they are primitive and if `call/cc` could be given a type, it would be `((a → b) → a) → a`.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that your transformation from `Con :: (∃x. t) -> T` to `Con :: ∀x. t -> T` is just currying, if you view the existential as a (weak) dependent pair.

Comment: @copumpkin: Can you elaborate on that?  How is existential quantification related to product types?

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Dependent pairs encode existential quantification under CH. For example, (∃n) n + 1 = 2 would be encoded as `Σ[ n ∶ ℕ ] (n + 1 ≡ 2)`, the proof then consists of witness and a proof that the witness satisfies the propositon, for example `(1 , refl)` (you can read `refl` as "follows from definition"). Compare it with dependent functions, which encode universal quantification. Function of type `(n : ℕ) → n ≡ 0 + n` transforms arbitary natural number into a proof that `n = 0 + n`.

Comment: I believe you should state _Not a **theorem:** P ⇔ ¬¬P_ etc. It really doesn't matter if it is axiom or not, what matters is that it is not a theorem of intuitionistic logic.

Comment: "(∀x. Q(x) ⇒ P)  =  (∃x. Q(x)) ⇒ P" should be "(∀x. Q(x) ⇒ P)  =>  (∃x. Q(x)) ⇒ P" , because the "step 2" -> "step 3" use double negation, but the reverse is not true. Not an axiom: P ⇔ ¬¬P (but P ⇒ ¬¬P is fine)  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I had a hard time informally understanding `∀x. (Q(x) ⇒ P)`  ⇔  `∃x. Q(x) ⇒ P`. I would translate it this way: `For all x: if x is a red cat, then Hans is scared.` ⇔ `If there exists at least one red cat, then Hans is scared`. So `Q(x) = x is a red cat?` and `P = Hans is scared`. This made it obvious to me. Not sure if it helps anyone else.

Comment: @hasufell: I had the same problem. Until this answer I didn't "see" the brackets. ie. ∃x. (Q(x) ⇒ P) vs. (∃x. Q(x)) ⇒ P. ∀x, makes total sense in the second case, since any Q(x) would trigger the implication.

Answer (score 11):

Plotkin and Mitchell established a semantics for existential types, in their famous paper,
which made the connection between abstract types in programming languages and existential types in logic,

> Mitchell, John C.; Plotkin, Gordon D.; [Abstract Types Have Existential
>   Type](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=45065), ACM Transactions on Programming Languages and Systems, Vol. 10,
>   No. 3, July 1988, pp. 470–502

At a high level,

> Abstract data type declarations appear in typed programming languages like Ada, Alphard, CLU and ML. This form of declaration
>   binds a list of identifiers to a type with associated operations, a
>   composite “value” we call a data algebra. We use a second-order typed
>   lambda calculus SOL to show how data algebras may be given types,
>   passed as parameters, and returned as results of function calls. In
>   the process, we discuss the semantics of abstract data type
>   declarations and review a connection between typed programming
>   languages and constructive logic.

Answer (score 10):

It's stated in the haskell wiki article you linked. I'll borrow some lines of code and comments from it and try to explain.

```
data T = forall a. MkT a
```

Here you have a type `T` with a type constructor `MkT :: forall a. a -> T`, right? `MkT` is (roughly) a function, so for every possible type `a`, the function `MkT` have type `a -> T`.
So, we agree that by using that constructor we may build values like `[MkT 1, MkT 'c', MkT "hello"]`, all of them of type `T`.

```
foo (MkT x) = ... -- what is the type of x?
```

But what does happen when you try to extract (e.g. via pattern matching) the value wrapped within a `T`? Its type annotation only says `T`, without any reference to the type of the value actually contained in it. We can only agree on the fact that, whatever it is, it will have one (and only one) type; how can we state this in Haskell?

```
x :: exists a. a
```

This simply says that there exists a type `a` to which `x` belongs.
At this point it should be clear that, by removing the `forall a` from `MkT`'s definition and by explicitly specifying the type of the wrapped value (that is `exists a. a`), we are able to achieve the same result.

```
data T = MkT (exists a. a)
```

The bottom line is the same also if you add conditions on implemented typeclasses as in your examples.