# Existential quantification without data constructors

Tags: haskell, existential-type

It is easy to get existential quantification by packing dictionaries in data constructors.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data S where
  MkS :: Show a => a -> S

f :: Int -> S
f x = case x of
  0 -> MkS 0
  _ -> MkS "non-zero"
```

The relevant [section](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#existentially-quantified-data-constructors) in the GHC guide explicitly talks about "Existentially quantified data constructors". Is it possible to write the same code but without introducing extra data types and constructors, i.e., something with a signature like

```
f :: Int -> (exists a. Show a => a)
f x = case x of
  0 -> 0
  _ -> "non-zero"
```

If not, is there a documented reason for why this limitation exists? Avoiding adding a new quantifier?

Comment: `(exists a. Show a => a)` can always be rewritten as something like `forall c. Show b => (forall a. Show a => a -> c) -> b -> c.` This is similar to the connection in logic between existential quantification and universal quantification.

Comment: @ColinBarrett Did you really mean the `b` stuff to be there, and not just, say, `forall c. (forall a. Show a => a -> c) -> c`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Borrowing from Colin's comment and looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10753957/2682729), it is possible to write a CPS-ed version of the same code without an `exists` quantifier.

```
f' :: Int -> ((forall a. Show a => a -> r) -> r)
f' x = case x of
  0 -> \k -> k 0
  _ -> \k -> k "non-zero"
```

While this is not ideal, it certainly solves the problem without introducing extra data types.